# Default namespace for polymorphic url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have a namespaced admin section.  Here's a snippet from my routes.rb:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :contents
end

map.resources :contents
```

Within my admin namespace, right now I am using the following:

```
link_to content, admin_content_path(content)
```

But I want to do:

```
link_to content, content
```

Which is currently equivalent to:

```
link_to content, content_path(content)
```

Is there a way to have all links within views belonging to a controller be prefixed with a namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i am reading you correctly, you can do

```
link_to content, [:admin, content]
```

this should get you to admin_content_path(content).  assuming of course the content is a valid variable (looks like you took this code from a block in an index scaffold view).

There is no prefix to apply to all restful links in a view,  however.  May i suggest just using the restful notation of admin_content_path(content) henceforth.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mapping contents twice, which is weird. You don't need to use nested resources here, that is for the situation where admin is an object that has_many contents, which is unlikey in your case. I recommend dropping the nested resource and trying the following.

:path_prefix - Set a prefix to the routes with required route variables.

```
map.resources :contents, :path_prefix => '/admin'
```

Comment: I'm not using a nested resource - I'm using a namespace.

I have two references to contents because I want to have two different sets of views on it - admin and normal user.